# how to change label color on md-select

Tags: css, angular-material

Been working on trying to figure out how to change the color of the label on a md-select box, but seems to fail.

For other labels, you can do:

```
md-input-container label {
  color: #999999;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

But in md-select doesn't work, and I can't figure out why. Inspecting the element it is picked up, and I can't see any other css that should change it

This is the code for md-select

```
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <label>Want to be early adoptor?</label>
            <md-select ng-model="testertype">
                <md-option ng-value="type" ng-repeat="type in types">{{ type.name }}</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
```

Comment: Just use `md-select md-option{ color: red; }`

Comment: why don't you post this as an answer @Pugazh?

Comment: sorry, md-select md-option did nothing

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/oLAErP)

[image]

CSS

```
md-select ._md-select-value._md-select-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

If you inspect the element you will see this:

[image]